# Django: raw SQL and values_list() bug?

Tags: django

Doing something like

```
SomeModel.objects.extra(..).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

always returns an empty list

Is this a Django bug ? Or am I missing seomthing?

Comment: We don't know. You haven't shown the schema, data, or query.

Comment: I think it happens in any Query. Any schema.

Comment: No. Doing "SomeModel.objects.extra(..).values_list(flat=True) returns results".

Comment: http://code.djangoproject.com/search?q=extra+values_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#values):

> If you use a `values()` clause after an `extra()` clause, any fields defined by a `select` argument in the `extra()` must be explicitly included in the `values()` clause. However, if the `extra()` clause is used after the `values()`, the fields added by the `select` will be included automatically.